# Else-If / While Loop stuck

Tags: loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to make a program that takes input of a minimum and a maximum number and then generates a random number in that range. Then the user guesses a number and if it's too high, it outputs a messege.. If it's too low, it outputs a message. The part that i'm stuck at is when you guess the number correctly, the user inputs "Y" or "N" to run the program again.

My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class GuessingGame_V2
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print('\u000C');
        int min;
        int max;
        int userGuess;
        int numberGuesses = 1;   
        System.out.println("Enter the minimum number: ");
        min = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the maximum number: ");
        max = in.nextInt();
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomNumber = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        System.out.println("Enter your guess: ");
        userGuess = in.nextInt();
    String guessAgain = ("Y");
while(!guessAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
{         
    if( userGuess > randomNumber ){
        System.out.println("Your guess was to high! Guess again!");
        System.out.println("Input your new guess: ");
        userGuess = in.nextInt();
        numberGuesses++;
       }
    else if (userGuess < randomNumber ){
        System.out.println("Your guess was to low! Guess again!");
        System.out.println("Input your new guess: ");
        userGuess = in.nextInt();
        numberGuesses++;
       }
    else 
       {  
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you guessed the number!");
        System.out.println("It took " + numberGuesses + " tries");
        System.out.println("Guess another number? (Y/N)");
        guessAgain = in.next();
       }
    }
   System.out.println("Thank's for playing!");
   }
}
```

The problem comes when the user hits "Y" to restart the program. It doesn't restart and just displays the final message again. (print statement, number of guesses, and Y/N). I need the program to restart when the user types "Y"

I'm new to posting on the site.. so forgive me if I messed up putting in the code -
Thanks in advance for the help -

*Changes - 11/13/13 10:58 Changed the code to take more than one input and to
keep taking input until the user gets it right.

Comment: Doesn't this code only allow them to guess once before starting a new game? If so, thats the problem you should be fixing first.

Comment: Yea you're right, I actually was playing with the code a little before I posted it here. I had it so that you could guess more than once and I've changed it back. Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Answer (score 0):

You need nested loops because you are doing two repetitive actions--first is repeating the game and second is prompting for guesses within one game.

So use nested loops. One loop prompts the user if he or she wants to play and prompts the user again with the same question at the end. The nested loop should be as you have it.

Your code should be along the lines of

```
while (stillPlaying) {
  while (stillGuessing) {
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Again, I'm relatively new to this.. Where would that go? Would that go in place of my "while(!guessAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))"? Also do I then have to define stillGuessing, and stillPlaying?

Also take note that I edited the code -

Comment: You don't necessarily need `boolean` variables, but you need conditions that are set based on the user responses. So you will have a condition that evaluates to `false` when the user guesses the right number in the inner loop. And a condition that evaluates to `false` when the user indicates with an "N" that he/she no longer wishes to play in the outer loop. The easiest way to begin this is to just implement the inner loop first--the game being played properly once.